# Missing hive table and cannot delete or create a new one

Tags: sql, hive, databricks

Working in Databricks, I'm having the issues that the following is happening. It seems that whilst I can "drop" the table, I cannot create a new table with the same name. I think its orphaned.

```
AnalysisException: Can not create the managed table('`spark_catalog`.`db`.`table`'). The associated location('s3://idl-xxxxxx-xxxxxx.db/table') already exists.
```

The following command gives an `OK` status

```
%sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.table;
```

But the following results in the error message

```
%sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.table (
  xxxa string
, xxxb string
, xxxc string
, xxxd string
, xxxe string
, xxxf string
)
USING parquet partitioned by (event_date, stem);
```

To be able to create the table

Answer (score 0):

> Working in Databricks, I'm having the issues that the following is happening. It seems that whilst I can "drop" the table, I cannot create a new table with the same name. I think its orphaned.

Yes, I think you need to remove the orphaned location.

This way:

```
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://<orphaned-location>
```

If you need to identify the orphaned location, try to execute this command:

```
SELECT location FROM db.table;
```

And then finally you can create the new table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.table (
  xxxa string
, xxxb string
, xxxc string
, xxxd string
, xxxe string
, xxxf string
)
USING parquet partitioned by (event_date, stem);
```

Comment: when I do this I get the following: PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'replace': extra input 'replace'(line 9, pos 48)

Comment: `CREATE or REPLACE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` also does not work